# how to uncheck a checkbox with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, prop

I have an issue with unchecking a check box.

I have this code in my html (php)

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 pr-1">
        <label>Modele</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="btn-group paymentBtnGroup btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <?
                    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        $i = 1;
                        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                            echo "<label class='btn paymentMethod'>";
                            echo "<div class='method col-sm' style='background-image: url(" . "assets/img/produits/".$row["IMAGEPATH"].")'>";
                            echo "</div>";
                            echo "<input type='radio' aria-labelledby='".$row["NOM"]."' value='".$row["K_MODELE"]."' name='modele' id='modele$i'>";
                            echo "</label>";
                            $i++;
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I try with a function to uncheck it once the form is added to my array.

so in my Jquery I try to use this line

```js
    $('.paymentBtnGroup input[type="radio"][name="modele"]').each(function(){
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
```

but it give an undefined error for my radiobuttons and it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: *"but it give an undefined error"* - Which is what *exactly?*

Comment: yeah, if i check my sources in chrome, this value is undefined. i give the name of the radiobuttons and it don't find it.

Comment: my id's of the elements are incremented with an $i so i can't get different values in my jquery

Comment: Your selector isn't using IDs so it doesn't matter what they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` doesn't mean what you think it means. But you can simplify to this:

```
$('.paymentBtnGroup input[type="radio"][name="modele"]').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: Can you explain why `$(this)` isn't what you think, he thinks it is :)

Comment: In OP's case, `this` is each checkbox and is used within the `each` as each checkbox - what do you think OP thinks `this` is inside the loop?

Comment: You're right, I mis-read - `$(this)` is what they thought it was. `this` wasn't, but that wasn't what they'd written.

Comment: finally it works! i need to disable the active class too because it gives like it was always checked

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your DOM is ready before applying any jquery

put script inside $(function(){});

```
$(function(){
  $('.paymentBtnGroup input[type="radio"][name="modele"]').each(function(){
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
});
```

Comment: its inside an function called in an on.click event, so when i add this form it give me an undefined error when it's fired